# Multiple Xcodes, how to choose which opens xcodeproj files

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, macos, xcode4.6

I have an issue with multiple versions of Xcode, as one overrides the **open** command for **xcodeproj** files.

When I set (in the information window) the default app for this type of file to the oldest Xcode and apply it for all of them it changes back automatically to newest.

How do I effectively change this?
I really need to use the older version for development.

Regards.

Comment: Stop trying to white-knight this NDA BS. It is **not** your job to be the police of this stuff.

Comment: To Richard's point the beta covers features within <insert your beta Apple Software>, not its existence as you can read about XCode5 without signing into the dev portal. XCode projects defaulting to one app or another aren't NDA-sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is an "issue" per se as my experience with the betas over the years has always done this. I know this isn't a solid answer as a "solution" but whenever I have a beta XCode installed I always open the current-release XCode first and open up my project files with CMD-O. Second option is what you're alluding to which is right-clicking to open the project file and choosing the appropriate version. The last option you've got is to uninstall/delete the beta XCode.

Comment: I think I'll delete one of the Xcodes as my git manager only has a simple "Open xcode project" command. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Are you not able to manually open Xcode an then the project? How can you write an app if such a basic usage makes problems?

Comment: No need to be condescending on here, folks. Not everyone is on the same playing field experience-wise. Perhaps that was just a translation issue (?)